SQL design - storing the index of each `Message` in each `Room`


Suppose I have two tables - Message and Room.

How would I find an index of each Message belonging to each Room?
Should I use a sequence for that, creating a new one for each Room?
Or calculate index using a trigger?
Maybe index shouldn't be stored at all and calculated dynamically? Would that be a good idea and be performant?
I wanted to account for the possibility of a client sending a very long message that would be automatically split into two messages with identical timestamps. (on the client's side, with a special API method made for sending split messages) Should I think about it some other way?
I'm also concerned about concurrency. I don't want two messages accidentally have the same index number.
Additionally, would it be possible to make sure there are no "gaps" between indexes?
So that it never can go like this:
1, 2, 4, 5, 8 ...`

If that over-complicates things, I can do without it.


Why have an index? Have a timestamp instead, it will be way more useful and you can easily order messages with it. No?

@Salketer Well 2 comments could come in at exactly the same time, and maybe would be assigned the same timestamp.  Not likely, but still possible.

Yes, but would it really be bad? What do you want to use that column for?

@Salketer I wanted to account for the possibility of a client sending a very long message that would be automatically split into two messages with identical timestamps. (on the client's side, with a special API method made for sending split messages)
Should I think about it some other way?

If you ask me, I wouldn't split a message, period. In any case, if you need to split it, the auto-incremental ID should suffice to discern which one should be first.

yes agree with @Salketer, splitting the message would introduce complexities like you would have to handle it separately to identify two rows were part of same message etc

As others have suggested, replace index in message with a timestamp. The message id should already be sequential, so having another sequenced column doesn't add any value whereas a timestamp conveys additional information. Don't worry about gaps in sequenced items: those will occur if data is deleted so there's no real value in preventing them. The only requirement should be that sequenced values are monotonically increasing. Using triggers to assign sequential values is both inefficient and unreliable: don't do it.

Please don't post details that can be adequately presented as text as images. The table structure can be presented as DDL.

@JohnH I'll post something like that as text next time

What do you mean with "How would I find an index of each Message belonging to each Room?" Is this when you insert the message? Or when you search a message with a select? The id column of message already provides a unique field if it is a primary key.

I wanted to account for the possibility of a client sending a very long message that would be automatically split into two messages You are aware that the TEXT data type can hold up to 1GB of data? And that 1GB is good for a few thousand books? Do you really think your users will produce so much content for a single message?
